# md-autocomplete material angular 4 работа с объектом

Tags: angular2, autocomplete

Делаю автокомплит на angular 4. С массивом строк работает без проблем фильтр вот в таком виде:

```
  filterStates(val: any) {
return val ? this.stateList.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0)
 : this.stateList;
```

а вот как работать с массивом объектов, ума не приложу. Оф документацию смотрел - не разобрался.

Comment: `for ... in` не о чем не говорит?

Comment: смотря что вы подразумеваете под "работать с массивом объектов". Фильтровать объекты по какому то полю? или по полному совпадению объектов?

Comment: этим уже разобрался, но автокомплит вещь очень специфическая)  Потом были проблемы с выводом нескольких автокомплитов на страницу, при то что я не знаю сколько их будет. Потом проблемы уничтожением ненужных автокоплитов. В общем кошмар)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

```js
 filterStates(val: any) {
return val ? this.stateList.filter(s => s.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0)
 : this.stateList;}
```